# ArabLuaTeX brackets and empty line

Tags: brackets, arabic, right-to-left, arabluatex, empty-line

Here's a strange behaviour when using square brackets, only in the `{arab}` environment when an empty line precedes the brackets.

This is how the problem output looks

[image: arabluatex-empty-line-bracket]

It happens only with square brackets, not with parentheses or angle brackets. Here is a MWE:

```
%!TEX TS-program = lualatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{arabluatex}
    \newfontfamily\arabicfont{Amiri}[Script=Arabic]

\begin{document}

with textarab command :-) 

\arb{[fa.sl]: al-safaru min bAb al-mandab}\\

then with \{arab\} environment :-( \\

\begin{arab}
[fa.sl]: ha_dA kwayis

[fa.sl]: laysa kways

\end{arab}
\end{document}
```

I've tried several dirty quick fixes, but no success, and I have a bunch of lines beginning with those brackets!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well spotted!  This is due to the way `\par` is processed by the current release of `arabluatex`.

I just pushed a fix to this problem.  Could you retrieve it from either http://git.robertalessi.net/arabluatex or https://gitlab.com/ralessi/arabluatex and confirm that this is fixed in the development version?  ([Installation guidelines](https://gitlab.com/ralessi/arabluatex#installation))